# convert MySQL SET data type to Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to convert a MySQL database to Postgres. It is frustrating, but proceeding along steadily. One issue that has me stumped is to convert the MySQL SET data type to Postgres. A SET data type in MySQL is not the same as the plain ENUM type, and can't be emulated with a CHECK constraint.

As far as I understand, a SET type allows storing zero or more values from the set in the column. So, something like the following in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE foo (color SET('red','green','blue'));
```

will allow any of the following as valid values

```
''
'red'
'red,blue'
'green,red'
```

and so on. A close approximation in Postgres is

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    color VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    CHECK (color IN ('red','green','blue'))
);
```

but the above doesn't allow 'red,blue' or 'green,red' and so on.

Of course, the above is just a simplification. The actual database is fairly more complicated with about half a dozen columns defined as SET.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use an array for the column and an ["is contained by"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) operator for the CHECK constraint:

```
create table pancakes (
    color varchar(10)[] not null,
    check (color <@ ARRAY['red', 'green', 'blue']::varchar[])
);
```

And then things like this happen:

```
=> insert into pancakes values (ARRAY['red']);
INSERT 0 1
=> insert into pancakes values (ARRAY['red','green','blue']);
INSERT 0 1
=> insert into pancakes values (ARRAY['red','green','blue','black']);
ERROR:  new row for relation "pancakes" violates check constraint "pancakes_color_check"
=> select * from pancakes;
      color       
------------------
 {red}
 {red,green,blue}
(2 rows)
```

This will allow `{red,red}` in the column though; if disallowing `{red,red}` is important, then you could add a function to check for unique color values in the array and adjust the CHECK constraint:

```
create function has_unique_colors(varchar[]) returns boolean as $$
    select (select count(distinct c) from unnest($1) as dt(c)) = array_length($1, 1);
$$ language sql;

create table pancakes (
    color varchar(10)[] not null,
    check (color <@ ARRAY['red', 'green', 'blue']::varchar[] and has_unique_colors(color))
);
```

Another option would be a pile of association tables with simple scalar values in the columns. However, this might be cumbersome if you have six of these columns. You could also use Erwin's version of the function if you needed to worry about NULLs in the "sets":

```
create function has_unique_colors(varchar[]) returns boolean as $$
    select not exists(select c from unnest($1) dt(c) group by 1 having count(*) > 1);
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Great answer. At first reading, it doesn't help me; not because it allows red,red, but because it seems to store data with those curly braces. However, I guess I could retrieve values and join them with a comma. This well might work. I have been researching, and there doesn't seem to be any other solution. Thanks.

Comment: oooohh... I take my comment back. The answer is still great, but doesn't work for me at all. Prime reason is, I can't actually convert the existing 1 million+ rows in MySQL to Postgres without actually changing the data in the process.

Comment: @punkish: I added a way around the uniqueness problem. The braces are just how PostgreSQL displays arrays. There is an `array_to_string` function if you really want them to come out of the database in as a single string. Whatever interface you're using might understand the arrays and convert them to arrays-in-your-language too.

Comment: @punkish: Your second comment doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Dealing with a simple data format conversion is going to be the least of your problems during any database migration.

Comment: hmmmm... I didn't know of the `array_to_string` function. Wrt data format conversion, I will have to convert the existing strings in the MySQL column to an array insert statement for Pg. I will try this out. Hopefully it will work. Thanks again.

Comment: The [`regex_split_to_array`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) function might be of use as well.

Comment: @punkish: A somewhat faster test, that also works with `NULL` in the ARRAY: `SELECT NOT EXISTS(SELECT c FROM unnest($1) t(c) GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)`

Comment: @Erwin: Thanks, that's a nice way around the NULL problem.