# array_append if element not exists

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert MySQL SET data type to Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424283/convert-mysql-set-data-type-to-postgres)

I have postgresql 8.4.

I am trying to build up a query without success. I would like to insert elements into an array if they are not exists in the conserning row.

TABLE "test":

```
+------------------+------------------+
| id               | varchar(20)      |
| timestp          | timestamp        |
| place            | varchar(20)      |
| myarray[][]      | varchar[14][254] |
+------------------+------------------+

+---------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
|  xyz    | 2010-01-01 10:10:10 | nowhere   |  "{abc,qwert}" |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

So I would like to add "{fgh,gfdsa}" to myarray WHERE (id='xyz' AND timestp="2010-01-01 10:10:10" AND place='nowhere') **IF it is not already in myarray**

I tried something like this>

```
UPDATE test
SET myarray = array_append(wascon2,'{fgh,gfdsa}') 
WHERE (id='xyz' AND timestp="2010-01-01 10:10:10" AND place='nowhere'
AND NOT EXISTS 1 FROM test WHERE (myarray='{fgh,gfdsa}')));
```

This doesnt work, it will append the array every time when I call it.

```
+---+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|xyz|2010-01-01 10:10:10|nowhere|{"{abc,qwert}","{fgh,gfdsa}","{fgh,gfdsa}"}|
+---+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

If think I should use >

```
myarray = ANY ('{fgh,gfds}'::varchar[])
```

somehow but I cant find out how..

The best wolud be a plpgsql function for me.

Comment: One possible solution after several tries>
UPDATE test
SET myarray=array_append(myarray,'{fgh,gfdsa}')
WHERE id=xyz
AND timestp="2010-01-01 10:10:10"
AND place='nowhere'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test where '{fgh,gfdsa}' =ANY(myarray)));

This may have side effects or hidden faults. I have to test it well. Also no experience on performance in bigger DBS...

Comment: Looks to me as though you want a SET type in Postgres.  [Convert MySQL SET data type to Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424283/convert-mysql-set-data-type-to-postgres) suggests ways it can be done and applies to your scenario directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE test
    SET myarray = myarray || array['fgh','gfdsa']::varchar[][]
    WHERE
        id = 'xyz'
        AND timestp = '2010-01-01 10:10:10'
        AND place = 'nowhere'
        AND not(myarray @> array['fgh','gfdsa']::varchar[][])
    ;
```

Comment: It gives me> "no operator matches the given name and argument types" for the double "|" sign

Comment: perfect. thanks for the answare and for the editing.